# Android swipe listener in fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, ontouchlistener

I'm following this tutorial http://www.brightec.co.uk/ideas/android-listview-alphabet-scroller to implement an alphabet list view with a side view containing letters that you can scroll to make the list view scroll directly to that letter. It works well with their example, however I neet to put this code in a fragment, and the scroll doesn't work anymore. I don't know how to transform the following so it works in a fragment:

```
private class SideIndexGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
        Log.d("DEBUG", "SideIndexGestureListener.onScroll() distanceX=" + distanceX + " distanceY=" + distanceY);
        // we know already coordinates of first touch
        // we know as well a scroll distance
        sideIndexX = sideIndexX - distanceX;
        sideIndexY = sideIndexY - distanceY;

        // when the user scrolls within our side index
        // we can show for every position in it a proper
        // item in the country list
        if (sideIndexX >= 0 && sideIndexY >= 0) {
            displayListItem();
        }

        return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tired doing the following:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_fragment_contacts, container, false);

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new SideIndexGestureListener());

    rootView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

But it never reaches the onScroll methos so I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I fiddled a bit with the code and managed to make it work by always returning true in the onTouch method of the listener I set to the rootwiew.